# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{2-x} xyz\, dz\, dy\, dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{2-x} xyz\, dz\, dy\, dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{2-x} xyz\, dz\, dy\, dx
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x} \left[\frac{xyz^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{2-x}\,dy\, dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x} \left(\frac{xy(2-x)^2}{2}\right)\,dy\, dx
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x} \left[\frac{xy^2(2-x)^2}{4}\right]_{0}^{1-x} dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1} \left[\frac{x(1-x)^2(2-x)^2}{4}\right]\,dx
=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x(x^2-2x+1)(x^2-4x+2)}{4}dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{x^5}{4} -\frac{3x^4}{2}+\frac{11x^3}{4}-2x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right) \,dx$$

$$= \left.\left((\frac{x^6}{24} -\frac{3x^5}{10}+\frac{11x^4}{16}-\frac{2x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\right|_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{80}$$

Is there a simpler way to solve this integral? Especially on the last integration of $dx$?

Comment: The actual value of the integral is 13/240, according to Mathematica.

Comment: While it may appear to be an involved calculation, integrals of three variables really don't get much easier than this one... It is an iterated integral, and the final integrand is a polynomial in $x$.

Comment: $(2-x)^2 = (x^2-4x+\mathbf{4})$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a much shorter way, but perhaps arranging things in some ways is better than in other ways. In your case I'd write:

$$\int_01 x\,dx\int_0^{1-x}y\,dy\int_0^{2-x} z\,dz=\int_0^1 x\,dx\int_0^{1-x}y\,dy\frac12(x-2)^2=$$

$$\frac12\int_0^1x(x-2)^2dx\frac12(x-1)^2=\frac14\int_0^1x(x^2-4x+4)(x^2-2x+1)dx=$$

$$=\frac14\int_0^1\left(x^5-6x^4+13x^3-12x^2+4x\right)dx=\frac14\left(\frac16-\frac65+\frac{13}4-4+2\right)=$$

$$=\frac14\left(\frac{10-72+195}{60}-2\right)=\frac{13}{240}$$

If not shorter at least it gives, perhaps, a little more chance to catch mistakes...